# navbar dropdown causing page width to extend

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 beta 2.

I have a right-aligned navbar and when I click on the dropdown, the page extends right-wards. What am I doing wrong

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white" id="alertNavBar">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end ">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Alerts <i class="fa fa-bell"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Messages <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Settings <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">App Config</a>
        </div>
      </li>     

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As a temporary fix, I've put a `container` class on the first div in the navbar. Is there some way that's better than this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the class `.dropdown-menu-right` to your `.dropdown-menu` as per Bootstrap's documentation on Menu Alignment:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment